# variable dataframe in R

Tags: r

Say I have loaded a csv file into R with two columns (column A and column B say) with real value entries. Call the dataframe df. Is there away of speeding up the following code:

```
dfm <- df[floor(A) = x & floor(B) = y,]
x <- 2
y <- 2
dfm
```

I am hoping there will be something akin to function e.g.

```
dfm <- function(x,y) {df[floor(A) = x & floor(B) = y,]}
```

so that I can type

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that's written right now won't work for a few reasons:

1. You need to assign values to `x` and `y` before you assign `dfm`. In other words, the lines `x <- 2` and `y <- 2` must come before the `dfm <- ...` line.
2. `R` doesn't know what `A` and `B` are, even if you put them inside the brackets of the dataframe that contains them. You need to write `df$A` and `df$B`.
3. `=` is the assignment operator, but you're looking for the logical operator `==`. Right now your code is saying "Assign the value x to `floor(A)`" (which doesn't really make sense). You want to tell it "Only choose rows where `floor(A)` equals x", or `floor(A)==x`.

So what you want is:

```
dfm.create <- function(x,y) {df[floor(df$A)==x & floor(df$B)==y,]}
dfm <- dfm.create(2,2)
```

Note that if you want the dataframe to be called `dfm`, you don't want to name the function `dfm`, or you will have to erase the function to make the dataframe.

Comment: sorry, I was a bit forgetful with some of it. e.g. I would have written attach(df) so that A and B were well - defined. Thanks for reminding me about about the difference between = and ==. As a newbie to R this is something I am forgetting! I am glad to see that the actual function works in this case though. Cheers!